# Under GCH, the countable support product of Prikry Silver forcing is $\omega_2$-cc

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I came across a statement in the David and Osvaldo’s paper “[There are no P-points in Silver extension](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02082)” that:

> under GCH, it is a well-known fact that $\omega_1 < \kappa$ copies of the countable support product of Prikry Silver forcing is $\omega_2$-cc.

However, as I am not familiar with the concept of countable support product and Prikry Silver forcing, I was unable to prove this. What would be the approach to proving this claim?

As for Prikry Silver forcing, I have been reading Halbeisen's combinatorial set theory and for countable support product, I have been reading Kunen's Set theory.

Comment: How many copies are you putting into the product? In general, this should just be a cardinality argument mixed with a bit of a $\Delta$-system argument on the supports, since Prikry-Silver forcing has size continuum, which is $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Given a lack of familiarity with the notions central to your problem (countable support product and Prikry Silver forcing), it might be better to take a step back and ask about how those notions are defined in the context of the paper (you give a title but no author or date or other publication details).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your response. I was trying to put  κ(>ω1) copies into the product, but thanks to you, I now understand what I should do.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your response.
I have added the link to the paper and references of Prikry Silver forcing and countable support product. However, I have not been able to obtain much detailed information on countable support product. Do you know of any good reference books on this topic?

Comment: You might want to look at the proof that a countable support product of Sacks reals is proper.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would it be possible for you show me any references that contain the claim and a proof?